# How to retrieve summary elements from S4 class object?

Tags: r, arules

I'm doing some in-line calculations in R Markdown. Just wondering how to retrieve summary elements of transactional data? Here is the code I have so far:

```
## Libraries
library(arules)

## Data
data("Adult")

## Other summaries
length(Adult)    # no. transactions
dim(itemInfo(Adult))[[1]]    # no. distinct items
```

What I'm trying to get is the **density** of the itemset. These are the things I have tried:

```
str(summary(Adult))

summary(Adult)$density
summary(Adult)[["density"]]
Adult$density
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to give.

Comment: `summary(Adult)@density`

Comment: The output of `str(summary(Adult))` actually shows you the appropriate operator for accessing S4 slots.

Comment: Oh I'm silly. Thank you.